# Understanding raster symbology settings

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, resampling

I am trying to understand how to use the symbology options for raster layers in QGIS, particularly the Resampling options, but the official documentation only mentions the setting very briefly and doesn't go into detail about how they work.

I am interested in how to use the settings to best view raster images such as topographic maps or nautical charts, either via tileset map services or offline static formats like GeoTIFF. Most videos and tutorials I can find seem to deal with resampling for data manipulation purposes rather than display purposes.

EDIT: The existing answers about Lanczos resampling are quite informative and will be useful as I go a bit further. However, my question isn't really about different interpolation methods, which I understand fairly well, but rather about what effect the specific settings in QGIS have on rendering the raster layer.

Normally, I would investigate this by changing the settings and visually comparing the result, but I don't see any difference when I apply them (other than the image not rendering at all under certain settings at certain zoom levels). In short, I don't understand from the setting names how I should expect them to affect the image. Specifically:

- What are the "zoomed in" and "zoomed out" settings, and what steps should I take to compare them visually? Are these related to upsampling and downsampling, as described in the Lanczos article?
- What is "oversampling", and how does it affect an image visually?
- Are any of the other symbology settings relevant to the visual appearance of something like a topographic map?

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/what-is-lanczos-resampling-useful-for-in-a-spatial-context which has some very interesting comparisons between methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Lanczos resampling useful for in a spatial context?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/what-is-lanczos-resampling-useful-for-in-a-spatial-context)

Comment: Thanks; very informative! However, my question is actually a bit more rudimentary—I've edited the question to explain how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edited answer (11-SEP-2018)**

The following answers and descriptions are based on QGIS 3.2. They will not touch on interpolation methods since the questioner is already familiar with them.

I assume that the question specifically asked about the settings in *Layer Properties* -> *Symbology* -> *Resampling* (as in the figure below)

[image: Figure 1]

**Zoomed In - Nearest Neighbour, Bilinear, Cubic**

Generally, this setting kicks in when User "zooms in" (i.e., towards ground) past the raster layer's native pixel resolution. Please see the figure below for the effect. (Be sure to keep the *Oversampling* value at 1.0 or higher. The default is 2.0.)

Specifically - this setting was meant to take effect when the map view's pixel resolution is larger than the raster layer's original (i.e., file) pixel resolution.

[image: Figure 2]

**Zoomed Out - Nearest Neighbour, Average**

Generally, this setting kicks in when User "zooms out" (i.e., away from ground) past the raster layer's native pixel resolution. Please see the figure below for the effect. (Be sure to keep the *Oversampling* value at higher than 1.0. The default is 2.0.)

Specifically - this setting was meant to take effect when the map view's pixel resolution is smaller than the raster layer's original (i.e., file) pixel resolution.

The *Average* method is actually a bilinear interpolation. Under most situations, *Oversampling*'s default value of 2.0 gives "best" visual result vis-a-vis performance. For large orthophoto raster, larger *Oversample* values may give better visual results especially if the raster has many white spots (e.g., due to light reflections off cars, rooftops, water bodies, poor-quality map production, combinations of the aforementioned, and etc.). But larger *Oversample* values also increase rendering duration, and may not necessarily produce better result. Different raster orthophotos give different visual results - so do experiment with different *Oversampling* values.

[image: Figure 3]

**The *Oversampling* Value**

The actual application and effect of *Oversampling* can be explained from the QGIS source codes reduced/simplified to the following steps:

```
let pixelRatio = map view's pixres / raster layer's pixres,
let toUseRatio = min(pixelRatio, Oversampling),
```

*toUseRatio* is the smaller of *pixelRatio* and *Oversampling*. Thus, *Oversampling* is a misnomer, and it should aptly be labeled **"Maximum Pixel Ratio"** instead.

```
// Assuming Zoom_In and/or Zoom_Out is not Nearest_Neighbour.

if toUseRatio < 1.0 or toUseRatio near 1.0 then
    resamplerToUse = interpolation specified in Zoom_In
else if toUseRatio > 1.0 then
    resamplerToUse = interpolation specified in Zoom_Out
else 
    resamplerToUse = Nearest Neighbour
```

Next, QGIS decides between (the interpolation method specified in) *Zoom In* and *Zoom Out* using the above logic. The resulting "idiosyncrasy" is that *Zoom In* can be chosen over *Zoom Out* when User "zooms out" past the layer's native pixel resolution.

```
let resWidth  = map view's width * toUseRatio,
let resHeight = map view's height * toUseRatio,

let InpImg = Block(raster layer, map view's extent, resWidth, resHeight),
let OutImg = scale InpImg to map view's width and height using resamplerToUse.
```

And last - the image copying/scaling operation. If *toUseRatio* is "big", so will *resWidth* and *resHeight*, and this directly results in *InpImg* having more pixels across and down. *InpImg* is then scaled down (or up) to fit the map view's screen width and height.

If *InpImg* has more pixels (across and down) than the map view, then a scale down will occur, and the result will be "good". Conversely, if *InpImg* has less pixels (across and down) than the map view, then a scale up will occur, and the result will be poor. (See the figure below.)

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm asking about!

Could you explain a little more about what Oversampling does, and also how these settings would apply to raster layers that contain multiple tilesets within a single map service?

For example, the USGS topographic maps service contains different maps for the 1:250k, 1:100k and 1:24k scales, and these different scales display at different zoom levels. I've noticed that a higher Oversampling value sometimes results in the maps from a higher zoom level appearing, instead of those that normally are rendered for that zoom level. Why is this?

Comment: For a web map service (eg WMTS), QGIS automatically "locks in" on the best layer depending on your current map view's scale or pixel resolution. QGIS then "Zooms In" or "Zooms Out" until your map view reaches the next best layer. And the process repeats.

Comment: It is the User's map view's current (nominal scale) or pixel resolution that determine which web map service layer that QGIS loads -  and not any value in Oversampling.

Comment: What would account for the change, then? For example, at a scale of 1:125,000 and 2x magnification, with Oversampling set to 2.0, QGIS loads the 100k topo layer. At the same scale and magnification, with Oversampling set to 3.0, QGIS displays the 24k topo (though it does first render the 100k layer, which appears briefly at improved resolution until the 24k layer loads in its place).

Comment: May I suggest that you create a new entry for your (seemingly related) questions? This is for compliance with the forum guidelines. Moreover, the comment isn't a great place for putting answers.

Comment: Oversampling is one of the settings included in my initial question, but it does seem that we've uncovered a sub-topic of enough complexity to warrant its own entry. At the least, if I understand your answer here, there is a discrepancy between my observation of the Oversampling setting, and your explanation of how it works (or is supposed to work)—perhaps a bug.

Comment: A separate question on Oversampling is now posted here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295565/how-does-oversampling-work-in-wmts-layers