# Increasing resolution of raster, having the coordinates match a reference raster and interpolating missing values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I have two rasters of different resolutions of the same country.

One raster contains information of Global Horizontal Irradiance (GHI) and has dimensions of 3200 × 2400. The other raster contains information of Temperature and has dimensions of 960 × 720. The coordinates of both rasters don't exactly match.

I'd like to increase the resolution of the Temperature raster, interpolate the missing values with which ever method is considered preferable, and have the same coordinates as the GHI raster.

If visualized as a CSV file, I'd expect both files to have the same number of rows and columns, and (Latitude, Longitude). However different information, since one file would contain Temperature and the other GHI.

Comment: Are the two rasters in the same coordinate reference system?

Comment: and do they have the same spatial extent? rows and columns do not necessarily equate to cell size. Regardless, degrading your smaller cells to match your larger ones is the more accurate alternative.. there is a really good post on resampling methods that is worth reading if you're trying to interpolate https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/what-is-lanczos-resampling-useful-for-in-a-spatial-context/14361#14361

Comment: Both have the same CRS and spatial extent.

Answer (score 2):

Use ["Warp (reproject)"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#warp-reproject) with temp raster as input. You can leave the Source and Target CRS's empty if the rasters have the same coordinate system.

1. Set output file resolution to the same as the GHI raster. My GH raster is 1 m resolution and the temp raster 50 m.
2. Click "Show advanced parameters" and set "Georeferenced extents of output file to be created" to the GHI raster extent

[image]

Comment: I was able to increase the raster resolution and both have the same extent, but the pixels don't perfectly match.